# Declaring a winner in tic-tac-toe not sure what went wrong

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing an HTML/Javascript tic-tac-toe game that uses drag and drop.  Basically the player drags an x or o image onto the board, and the code I currently have to check for and declare a winner is just not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

.square {
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
padding: 10px;
border: 1px solid #aaa;
float: left;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
        helper:clone;
    }

    function drop(ev) {
        var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    var cell1 = null;
    var cell2 = null;
    var cell3 = null;
    var cell4 = null;
    var cell5 = null;
    var cell6 = null;
    var cell7 = null;
    var cell8 = null;
    var cell9 = null;

function onDrop(event) {
var id = event.target.id;
if (player1) {
  cell = 'o';
} else {
  cell = 'x';
}
checkForWinner();
}

function checkForWinner() {
if (cell1 === 'o' && cell2 === 'o' && cell3 === 'o') {
 return player1;
} else if (cell1 === 'x' && cell2 === 'x' && cell3 === 'x') {
 return player2;
} else if (cell4 === 'O' && cell5 === 'O' && cell6 === 'O') {
 return player1;
} else if (cell4 === 'x' && cell5 === 'x' && cell6 === 'x') {
 return player2;
} else if (cell7 === 'o' && cell8 === 'o' && cell9 === 'o') {
 return player1;
} else if (cell7 === 'x' && cell8 === 'x' && cell9 === 'x') {
 return player2;
} else if (cell1 === 'o' && cell4 === 'o' && cell7 === 'o') {
 return player1;
} else if (cell1 === 'x' && cell4 === 'x' && cell7 === 'x') {
 return player2;
} else if (cell2 === 'o' && cell5 === 'o' && cell8 === 'o') {
 return player1;
} else if (cell2 === 'x' && cell5 === 'x' && cell8 === 'x') {
 return player2;
} else if (cell3 === 'o' && cell6 === 'o' && cell9 === 'o') {
 return player1;
} else if (cell3 === 'x' && cell6 === 'x' && cell9 === 'x') {
 return player2;
} else if (cell1 === 'o' && cell5 === 'o' && cell9 === 'o') {
 return player1;
} else if (cell1 === 'x' && cell5 === 'x' && cell9 === 'x') {
 return player2;
} else if (cell3 === 'o' && cell5 === 'o' && cell7 === 'o') {
 return player1;
} else if (cell3 === 'x' && cell5 === 'x' && cell7 === 'x') {
 return player2;
}
}

</script>

<title>JavaScript  Drag &amp; Drop Tic-Tac-Toe</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>Drag the X and O images into the tic-tac-toe board:</p>
<table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td id="cell1" class="square" ondrop="drop(event)"    ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
        <td id="cell2" class="square" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
        <td id="cell3" class="square" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="cell4" class="square" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
        <td id="cell5" class="square" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
        <td id="cell6" class="square" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="cell7" class="square" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
        <td id="cell8" class="square" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
        <td id="cell9" class="square" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<img id="drag1" src="X.png" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="75" height="75"/>
<img id="drag2" src="O.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="75" height="75"/> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: getting any output in the console?

Comment: When I load the page, it just shows my 3x3 grid and the X and O image, which used to be draggable, but are not anymore.  http://i.imgur.com/pDk4fmY.png

Comment: I'd consider a bit mask for determining the winner

Answer (score 0):

your missing a closing curly bracket `}` at the end of the checkForWinner() function specifically the one to close out your last if conditional

```
 function checkForWinner() {
   if (cell1 === 'o' && cell2 === 'o' && cell3 === 'o') {
     return player1;
   /* ... */
   } else if (cell3 === 'x' && cell5 === 'x' && cell7 === 'x') {
     return player2;

   // vvv HERE vvv
   }

}
```

also the drop function is calling `checkForWinner()` which really isn't doing anything...

if you changed `player1`  & `player2` to string eg `"player1"` / `"player2"` you could attempt to do something like

```
function onDrop(event) {
    var id = event.target.id;
    if (player1) {
      cell = 'o';
    } else {
      cell = 'x';
    }
    if ( checkForWinner() === "player1" ) { alert("Player 1 Wins");}
    else if ( checkForWinnder() === "player2") { alert("Player 2 Wins"); }
}
```

but that is all up to you

Comment: I'm not sure I can see where I'm missing it exactly.  I have one after every return statement, no?

Comment: Thanks.  That fixed my drag and drop, but did not fix why my declaring a winner isn't working

Comment: id guess its like Alex said - `player1` and `player2` variables aren't declared - it looks to me like there's a chunk of this functionality missing

Comment: would that just be "var player1 = newPlayer();" ?

Comment: unless you've defined any player function that would be a no - i would suggest you take a look at google for some javascript tutorials to get a grasp of the fundamentals - like this one at w3 http://www.w3schools.com/js/

Comment: I tried that latest code you've posts with the player1 being string, but there was no alert when I tested the tic-tac-toe game.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have not defined `player1` and `player2`. If you hit <kbd>F12</kbd> in your browser, you should be getting an error.

Try putting these two lines at the beginning of your `checkForWinner()` function:

```
var player1 = 'player1';
var player2 = 'player2';
```

Then you have to check the output of that function to determine a winner, so where you have `checkForWinner();` in your `onDrop()` function, try this:

```
var winner = checkForWinner();
if(winner == 'player1' || winner == 'player2')
    alert(winner+' won!');
```

The `ondragstart` and `ondrop` handlers were not recognizing your function definitions, so I made them global by defining them on the `window` object and also you didn't have a `clone` helper function defined, so I made a blank one. Here is working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/9me7n/1/

The reason the alert isn't popping up is because you just set all of the cells equal to `null`. You need to set the correct cell's value to `x` or `o` in your `onDrop` function and then it should work flawlessly, assuming you have enough `if` statements for all of the possible game moves.

Comment: How do I define them?

Comment: Hmm.. I tried that, but there is still no alert coming up to declare a winner.  Here's a link to my script in jsfiddle just to see if I did it correctly:

http://jsfiddle.net/9me7n/

Comment: @user2923395 I've added all the info you need to my answer. The `checkForWinner()` function will not work until you correctly update the cell values in your `onDrop` function.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm not sure I understand what you mean with setting the correct cell's value to x or o in my onDrop function.   Do I not have that already with "(cell1 === 'o' && cell2 === 'o' && cell3 === 'o') { return player1;" etc?

Comment: @user2923395 There are a lot of problems with your code left in the `onDrop` function. In that function `player1` is not defined, also you should be setting the value of `cell1` `cell2` etc., not `cell`

Comment: oooh.  So should it be a long if statement like with my checkForWinner function?  like "if (player1) {
             cell1 = 'o';
         } else {
             cell1 = 'x';
         } etc, etc, etc?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40861/discussion-between-user2923395-and-alex-w)